# VBA: Syntax error when passing numeric value to a field using UPDATE

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here is my code

> Dim orderid As Long
>
> orderid = DMax("Number", "Orders", "") + 1
>
> DoCmd.RunSQL "Update Order_temp " _
>
> ```
>             & "Set Number = " & orderid & ", Name = '" & Me.Textbox & "' " _
>             & "WHERE (Name = '*')"
> ```

It works fine if it's only like this

> Dim orderid As Long
>
> orderid = DMax("Number", "Orders", "") + 1
>
> DoCmd.RunSQL "Update Order_temp " _
>
> ```
>             & "Set Name = '" & Me.Textbox & "' " _
>             & "WHERE (Name = '*')"
> ```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using square brackets when referencing fields of a table like so :

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [Order_temp] " _
        & "Set [Number] = " & orderid & ", [Name] = '" & Me.Textbox & "' " _
        & "WHERE ([Name] = '*')"
```

It will help avoiding conflicts on reserved words like Number.

Also I would edit a bit the other line as well :

```
orderid = Nz(DMax("Number", "Orders", ""),0) + 1
```

In order to avoid a Null exception.